# Git zombie branch won't go away

Tags: git, github

Every time I `git pull`, Git informs me that there is a new branch:

```
$ git pull
From github.com:MyAccount/myproject
 * [new branch]      brand/features/xyz -> origin/brand/features/xyz
Already up-to-date.

$ git pull
From github.com:MyAccount/myproject
 * [new branch]      brand/features/xyz -> origin/brand/features/xyz
Already up-to-date.
```

In GitHub, there's a branch called `brand/features/xyz`, but when I list remote branches in the terminal I only see one called `Brand/features/xyz`:

```
$ git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/Brand/features/xyz
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

I figure something needs to be pruned, but it doesn't fix the problem:

```
$ git remote prune origin
Pruning origin
URL: git@github.com:MyAccount/myproject
 * [pruned] origin/Brand/features/xyz

$ git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master

$ git pull
From github.com:MyAccount/myproject
 * [new branch]      brand/features/xyz -> origin/brand/features/xyz
Already up-to-date.

$ git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/Brand/features/xyz
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

There must be something wrong with "brand" vs "Brand", but how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour with a fresh `git clone` ? What branches do you see when you check via the github UI ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be mistaken about [`git remote prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), which removes *local* versions of a branch which have already been deleted remotely. Try the [following command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Deleting-Remote-Branches):

```
git push origin --delete Brand/features/xyz
```

Comment: Assuming the correct brand is spelled with a lowercase b, this will not delete it, will it?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to delete the branch on the server, my reading is that they want to delete their remote tracking branch...?

Comment: @EdwardThomson the branch on the server is spelled with a lowercase b, so I would prefer to keep it and have it stop creating this other one with a capital B.

Comment: What about the fact that two consecutive `git pull` operations report the same branch as being new?